# Why Won't the Canvas Load?

Tags: javascript, html

I have programmed a little game inside of tynker. It works perfectly normal fine inside of there. But when I bring it into a html file and load it in a browser, it is just a blank screen. I have known tynker to do some cheeky things to make your code work in that past. I wonder if there is some 'wakeup' function you have to call to make the script start. The problem is probably really obvious, I don't have that much programming experience.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id= "myCanvas" width= "500" height= "500"></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    // Set up background image
    var background = new Image();
    background.src = "/assets2/assets/57b614dfaf9231f5688b4576.png";
    background.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        start();
    }
    
    // Set up ships
    var pointsBiden = 0;
    var pointsTrump = 0;
    
    var image1 = new Image();
    var image1x
    var image1y
    
    var image2 = new Image();
    var image2x
    var image2y
    
    var donaldstop = false;
    var bidenstop = false;
    
    var bidenTurn = false;
    var trumpTurn = true;
    
    function wait(stop,waitsecs) {
        setTimeout(stop, waitsecs);
    }

    function donothing() {
        //
    }
    
    
    function start(){
            image1.src = "https://m-cdn.phonearena.com/images/article/78433-wide/Trump-other-GOP-presidential-hopefuls-take-shots-at-Apple-for-refusing-to-obey-a-court-order.webp";
            image1.onload = function(){
            image1x = 0;
            image1y = 250;
            ctx.drawImage(image1, image1x, image1y);
        }
            image2.src = "https://cdn.vanderbilt.edu/vu-news/files/20190417212447/Joe_Biden_slider-200x200.jpg"
            image2.onload = function(){   
            image2x = 300;
            image2y = 250;
            ctx.drawImage(image2, image2x, image2y);
        
           }
        }   
    

    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler);
    
    
    function keyDownHandler(event){
        if (event.keyCode == 32) {
            donaldstop = true;
            console.log("easter egg! (   your pretty cool :)  )")
            function fixTrump() {
                donaldstop = false;
            }
            wait(fixTrump, 1000)
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 9) {
            bidenstop = true;
            function fixBiden() {
                bidenstop = false;
            }
            wait(fixBiden, 1000)
        }
        
         if (donaldstop == false) {
           if (event.keyCode == 37) {
                image1x = image1x - 50;
           } else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
              image1y = image1y - 50;
           } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
              image1x = image1x + 50;
           } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
              image1y = image1y + 50;
           }
         }
        // Add cases for WASD keys, to change coordinates of image2
        if (bidenstop == false) {
            if (event.keyCode == 87) {
                image2y = image2y - 50;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 65) {
                image2x = image2x - 50;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 83) {
                image2y = image2y + 50;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 68) {
                image2x = image2x + 50;
            }
        }
        if (bidenTurn == true) {
            if (image1x == image2x && image1y == image2y) {
                image1x = 0;
                image1y = 250;
        
                image2x = 300;
                image2y = 250;
                pointsBiden = pointsBiden + 1;
                
                bidenTurn = false;
                trumpTurn = true;
            }
        }
        if (trumpTurn == true) {
            if (image1x == image2x && image1y == image2y) {
                image1x = 0;
                image1y = 250;
        
                image2x = 300;
                image2y = 250;
                pointsTrump = pointsTrump + 1;
                
                trumpTurn = false;
                bidenTurn = true;
            }
        }
        
        redraw();
    }
    
    
    
    function redraw() {

        if (trumpTurn == true) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                
                image2.src = "https://cdn.vanderbilt.edu/vu-news/files/20190417212447/Joe_Biden_slider-200x200.jpg"
                image2.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(image2, image2x, image2y);
            }
                image1.src = "https://m-cdn.phonearena.com/images/article/78433-wide/Trump-other-GOP-presidential-hopefuls-take-shots-at-Apple-for-refusing-to-obey-a-court-order.webp"
                image1.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(image1, image1x, image1y);
            }
         }
        
        if (bidenTurn == true) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                
            image1.src = "https://m-cdn.phonearena.com/images/article/78433-wide/Trump-other-GOP-presidential-hopefuls-take-shots-at-Apple-for-refusing-to-obey-a-court-order.webp"
            image1.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(image1, image1x, image1y);
            }
            image2.src = "https://cdn.vanderbilt.edu/vu-news/files/20190417212447/Joe_Biden_slider-200x200.jpg"
            image2.onload = function(){   
            ctx.drawImage(image2, image2x, image2y);
        
            }
        }
        
        
        ctx.font = "60px Verdana";
        ctx.fillText(pointsBiden, image2x + 80, image2y - 100);
        ctx.fillText(pointsTrump, image1x + 80, image1y - 100);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was messing around in the console with that code, and it always seems to say that the image failed to written to the canvas and stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the src you're providing for your background.

`"/assets2/assets/57b614dfaf9231f5688b4576.png"` is a relative path.  Meaning that when you were using this in tynker, you probably had a folder called "assets2" in your project, etc. which contained the file for the image you wanted to use as your background.  If you just move your code to an HTML file, without bringing other assets you're using within your code that are expected to be part of your project folder, you'll get an error.

Basically, you need to put your HTML file and any of the local images your project may be using into your project folder.  Then you should be able to run the game successfully.

Comment: oh yeah, it was one of their default images.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check in the directory provided in `background.src`, you might have provided a wrong directory, because on using link instead of that provided image this works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Set up background image
    var background = new Image();
    background.src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg"; // Changed this line only
    background.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      start();
    }

    // Set up ships
    var pointsBiden = 0;
    var pointsTrump = 0;

    var image1 = new Image();
    var image1x
    var image1y

    var image2 = new Image();
    var image2x
    var image2y

    var donaldstop = false;
    var bidenstop = false;

    var bidenTurn = false;
    var trumpTurn = true;

    function wait(stop, waitsecs) {
      setTimeout(stop, waitsecs);
    }

    function donothing() {
      //
    }


    function start() {
      image1.src = "https://m-cdn.phonearena.com/images/article/78433-wide/Trump-other-GOP-presidential-hopefuls-take-shots-at-Apple-for-refusing-to-obey-a-court-order.webp";
      image1.onload = function() {
        image1x = 0;
        image1y = 250;
        ctx.drawImage(image1, image1x, image1y);
      }
      image2.src = "https://cdn.vanderbilt.edu/vu-news/files/20190417212447/Joe_Biden_slider-200x200.jpg"
      image2.onload = function() {
        image2x = 300;
        image2y = 250;
        ctx.drawImage(image2, image2x, image2y);

      }
    }


    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler);


    function keyDownHandler(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 32) {
        donaldstop = true;
        console.log("easter egg! (   your pretty cool :)  )")

        function fixTrump() {
          donaldstop = false;
        }
        wait(fixTrump, 1000)
      }
      if (event.keyCode == 9) {
        bidenstop = true;

        function fixBiden() {
          bidenstop = false;
        }
        wait(fixBiden, 1000)
      }

      if (donaldstop == false) {
        if (event.keyCode == 37) {
          image1x = image1x - 50;
        } else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
          image1y = image1y - 50;
        } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
          image1x = image1x + 50;
        } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
          image1y = image1y + 50;
        }
      }
      // Add cases for WASD keys, to change coordinates of image2
      if (bidenstop == false) {
        if (event.keyCode == 87) {
          image2y = image2y - 50;
        } else if (event.keyCode == 65) {
          image2x = image2x - 50;
        } else if (event.keyCode == 83) {
          image2y = image2y + 50;
        } else if (event.keyCode == 68) {
          image2x = image2x + 50;
        }
      }
      if (bidenTurn == true) {
        if (image1x == image2x && image1y == image2y) {
          image1x = 0;
          image1y = 250;

          image2x = 300;
          image2y = 250;
          pointsBiden = pointsBiden + 1;

          bidenTurn = false;
          trumpTurn = true;
        }
      }
      if (trumpTurn == true) {
        if (image1x == image2x && image1y == image2y) {
          image1x = 0;
          image1y = 250;

          image2x = 300;
          image2y = 250;
          pointsTrump = pointsTrump + 1;

          trumpTurn = false;
          bidenTurn = true;
        }
      }

      redraw();
    }



    function redraw() {

      if (trumpTurn == true) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        image2.src = "https://cdn.vanderbilt.edu/vu-news/files/20190417212447/Joe_Biden_slider-200x200.jpg"
        image2.onload = function() {
          ctx.drawImage(image2, image2x, image2y);
        }
        image1.src = "https://m-cdn.phonearena.com/images/article/78433-wide/Trump-other-GOP-presidential-hopefuls-take-shots-at-Apple-for-refusing-to-obey-a-court-order.webp"
        image1.onload = function() {
          ctx.drawImage(image1, image1x, image1y);
        }
      }

      if (bidenTurn == true) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        image1.src = "https://m-cdn.phonearena.com/images/article/78433-wide/Trump-other-GOP-presidential-hopefuls-take-shots-at-Apple-for-refusing-to-obey-a-court-order.webp"
        image1.onload = function() {
          ctx.drawImage(image1, image1x, image1y);
        }
        image2.src = "https://cdn.vanderbilt.edu/vu-news/files/20190417212447/Joe_Biden_slider-200x200.jpg"
        image2.onload = function() {
          ctx.drawImage(image2, image2x, image2y);

        }
      }


      ctx.font = "60px Verdana";
      ctx.fillText(pointsBiden, image2x + 80, image2y - 100);
      ctx.fillText(pointsTrump, image1x + 80, image1y - 100);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```